# Is it possible to generate a gganimate plot with random numbers?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pi, gganimate

I wish to generate a `gganimate` object that shows n random points in a specific range. The other limitation is that it should plot `2^n` points, meaning `2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...` points. I did this to calculate the decimals of `pi` but I wish to plot this animation so I can show how it improves the results given more random numbers in a nicer way.

This is what I have so far:

```
results <- c()
for(i in c(1:20)) {
  r <- 1
  limit <- 2^i
  points <- data.frame(
    x = runif(limit, -r, r), 
    y = runif(limit, -r, r))
  points$d <- sqrt(points$x^2 + points$y^2)
  points$type <- ifelse(points$d < r, "c", "s")
  picalc <- 4 * length(points$type[points$type=="c"]) / limit
  error <- pi - picalc
  label <- paste0('Pi calc : ', round(picalc, 6), '\nError : ', round(error, 6))
  iter <- data.frame(n = limit, picalc = picalc, error = error, label = label)
  results <- rbind(results, iter)
}

# GGANIMATE
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
p <- ggplot(results, aes(x = runif(n, -1, 1), y = runif(n, -1, 1))) +
  geom_point(lwd = 2, alpha = 0.3) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = label), size = 5) + 
  labs(caption = 'Number of random points : {frame_time}') + 
  transition_time(n)
animate(p, nframes =  nrow(results), fps = 5)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what about this doesn't work how you want?

Comment: Thanks for your super fast reply @camille 
Instead of generating `n` random points in each iteration, it is doing this strange plot: https://makeagif.com/gif/gganimate-4jJ57j
Meaning the `frame_time` numbers are weird and no random points are generated, depending on that `n`

Comment: It seems like your "results" data frame is approximating pi using 2^n samples. Then you're pulling that into ggplot and adding a random dot to each frame using `aes(x = runif(n, -1, 1), y = runif(n, -1, 1)))`. What points did you want to display?

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring I wish to display first 2 random points, then 4, then 8, until I get to 2^20

Comment: @Bernardo: note that by using `results <- c(); results <- rbind(results, iter)`, you're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I would "show how it improves the results given more random numbers in a nicer way."

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
p <- ggplot(results, aes(x = n, y = error)) +
  geom_point(lwd = 2, alpha = 0.3) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = label), size = 5, hjust = 0) + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(2^(1:4), 4^(2:10)), minor_breaks = NULL) +
  labs(caption = 'Number of random points : {2^frame}') + 
  transition_manual(n) +
  shadow_trail(exclude_layer = 2)
animate(p, nframes =  nrow(results), fps = 5)
```

[image]

To show the kind of picture described in the question, you'd need to have the points labeled with the frame they belong to. (Also, as currently written, the points are randomly assigned afresh each iteration. It would be better to set all your points first, and then stick with those, in growing window sizes, to calculate the results.)

To do this quickly, I'm taking the last `points` frame (as it exists when `i` is at the end of the loop), and adding a number for what frame it should belong to. Then I can plot the points of each frame using `transition_manual`, and keep the past frames using `shadow_trail`.

Note, ggplot will be slower than I cared to wait if you run it with 1M points, so I did an abridged version up to 2^15 = 32k.

```
# Note, I only ran the orig loop for 2^(1:15), lest it get too slow
points2 <- points %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(),
         count = 2^ceiling(log2(row)))

point_plot <- ggplot(points2, 
                     aes(x = x, y = y, color = type, group = count)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6, size = 0.1) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(caption = 'Number of random points : {2^(frame-1)}') +
  transition_manual(count) +
  shadow_trail()
animate(point_plot, nframes = 15, fps = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is super useful!! You are right this plot is much better to explain the error reduction. But, how would you solve the original problem though? Thanks @jon-spring :)

Comment: Updated with one approach.